# Using system date format

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have WordPress theme and I am using `get_the_date` function to get the publish date of post :

```
<?php echo get_the_date( 'M-d-y' ); ?>
```

But it seems it will be better to use `get_option( 'date_format' ).`

How can I display post publish date using `get_option` function?

Comment: do you want to retrieve post data OR retrieve current post publish date?

Comment: only publish date

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't need to use `get_option` for getting post published date. You can get that by using `get_the_date` function properly.

**Here is the solution:**

1. Make the date appear as **Monday January 11, 2017**, use

   ```
   $post_date = get_the_date( 'l F j, Y' ); echo $post_date;
   ```
2. To make the date appear as **Wed Jan 9**, use

   ```
   $post_date = get_the_date( 'D M j' ); echo $post_date;
   ```

Read more about [get_the_date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) and check [date formatting](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) options here, in wordpress docs.